# Need to read the Excel data and push to Salesforce

Tags: apex

We have a requirement to read the data from excel (contain multiple worksheets) and push to Salesforce object. As we are not looking for app exchange apps, do we have any tool or package to achieve this requirement.

Any suggestions or inputs would be appreciated.

Note: We have tried to change the file type to csv but the data is not intact after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The [Salesforce Excel Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Force.com_Excel_Connector&oldid=1958) is a free plugin you can download for Excel in order to insert, update, and delete data in Salesforce. It's also possible to call the functions in this macro file in your own Excel scripts, allowing you to automate common data processes. Aside from this, there's not many other options available, short of writing your own tools.

Comment: thanks for the response